# update the state of an object in an array and change text style with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to change the style of a text and a property in an array when selected by a user. With my current script when a user taps on a selected text nothing happens

```
  addDay = (item) => {

    if(this.state.weekDays.indexOf(item.value) < 0){

      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        listDaysOfWeek: prevState.listDaysOfWeek.map(el => {
          if(el.value === item.value) {
            return {
              ...el,
              value: item.value,
              userSelected: true
            }
          }
          return el;
        })
      }, ()=> console.log(this.state.listDaysOfWeek)))
    }

  }
```

FlatList

```
<FlatList  numColumns={3}
                    data={this.state.listDaysOfWeek}  
                    renderItem={({item}) =>  
                        <Text 
                        onPress={() => this.addDay(item)}
                        style={item.userSelected ? styles.selectedDayOfWeek : styles.conceptHeader}>{item.name}</Text>}  
                />
```

Data Array

```
 this.state = {
      weekDays: [],
      listDaysOfWeek: [{ value: 1, name:  'Monday', userSelected: false }, { value: 2, name: 'Tuesday', userSelected: false  }, { value: 3, name: 'Wednesday', userSelected: false  },
      { value: 4, name: 'Thursday', userSelected: false  }, { value: 5, name: 'Friday', userSelected: false  }
    ]
    }
```

Any help on how to make this work as it should?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this might be the issue. Please provide import statements also, so someone can look into what library and UI components you're using. There are many libraries with ambiguous component names. (e.g. )

Change

```
addDay = (item) => {
```

to

```
addDay(item) { ...
```